# Inserir Cidades no banco Oracle

Tags: oracle

Alguém teria uma query para inserir no banco de dados Oracle todas as cidades brasileiras com acentuação e cedilha nas palavras?

Estou tentando encontrar alguma na internet, porém todas utilizam insert de mútiplos valores e no Oracle teria que escrever a sintaxe: `INSERT INTO TABELA VALUE VALOR` para cada cidade.

Já tenho a tabela criada com as colunas: `ID_MUNICIPIO`, `NM_MUNICIPIO` e `ID_ESTADO`.

Comment: Se você já tem um arquivo de texto com as cidades você pode fazer um replace com algum editor ex.: onde tem `,` substituir por `Insert into table (id_municipio, nm_municipio, id_estado)  values (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o link, nesse repositório tem bastante coisa: https://github.com/chandez/Estados-Cidades-IBGE em Municipios.sql você tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
Insert into Municipio (Codigo, Nome, Uf) values ('1100015','Alta Floresta D''Oeste', 'RO');
```

são mais de 5mil registros

Comment: Obrigado consegui usar esse repositorio.